# Unable to get youtube channel statistics using youtube data api v3

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have created the google project and using the youtube data api v3 key in below url but not getting channel statistics.

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?parts=statistics&id=UCQ_jR_iUmDsR50GX33qWvog&key=AIzaSyBDEjJeaI2QEzNuFNrjPAsFHl1Jin9JWsw`

Output is below

```
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "5PVGuDob8dxpfgpaJGWruEW8hV8",
  "pageInfo": {
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "Z0A5YSAnQtcEnTTvtERboPwQAk0",
      "id": "UCQ_jR_iUmDsR50GX33qWvog"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working with [channel.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) I think you should check your code I just tested this with your same request and it works fine from here.  [tryme](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22statistics%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22UCQ_jR_iUmDsR50GX33qWvog%22%5D%7D&apix=true)

Request:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCQ_jR_iUmDsR50GX33qWvog&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \ 
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Response

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "1a3o4gpa3kaJyNIWXi2yvRgmk4s",
  "pageInfo": {
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "S7lD_zHbbGaTaOHU3iEyjECpr0c",
      "id": "UCQ_jR_iUmDsR50GX33qWvog",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "488",
        "commentCount": "0",
        "subscriberCount": "2",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "13"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## anwsers from comment questions

> How your project is able to access my youtube channel?

You are using an API key that grants access to public data.  Which is what i am doing as well.  Stats on your channel is public data.

> Like you testing it on browser it is working but I copy the same python code to my local machine and try to run it is promoting for key.

You didn't post your code i cant help you with that.  What you have shown shows a hard coded public key= paramater.

> how to bypass or get rid of prompt?

I am using a public api key there is no prompt as its requesting public data.

Comment: okay. I have many questions on this. How your project is able to access my youtube channel? Like you testing it on browser it is working but I copy the same python code to my local machine and try to run it is promting for key. how to bypass or get rid of prompt?

Comment: I have updated my answer to answer all those questions :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But the link you have provided under "try this" there is a python tab in the end. I am copying and pasting same python code on my local and try to run that. But that code is prompting for authorization code

Comment: Thats because try me uses Oauth2 for authentication, the mentioned you are using doesn't require oauth access it can be queried using an API key.  I suggest you look around on how to use the google python client library with Python and open a new question if you have any issues with that.  As its out of scope for this question.